# What do ios apps do when they 'load?'

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, loading

Most apps I see have loading screens, presumably to prevent hiccups in the game and to pre-load all of the data needed later in the game. I am currently working on a game that skips every few frames, presumably because the image data for the objects being rendered to the screen are not being held in memory. What do programmers actually do to hold this data  in memory throughout the time the app is running? I can think of using arrays, such as `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` to hold the images, however I still struggle to see how that would improve the performance of the app. Perhaps I am totally going off on a tangent here. A word of advice from someone with experience in the area would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

For the person who voted to close the question, my question, more specifically, is this: What is a typical method in which an ios game loads its data into active memory to enable easy and low-overhead access during run time?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but depending your game type I'd suggest using tmx mapping.

Comment: Fitzy, "Apple" does some loading stuff when the **actual 'loading screen'"** is displayed.  In 95% of apps, the first scene you cut to has a perfectly matching image of the same loading screen image.  But then it's "you" doing your own loading.  It's difficult to say "what" you should do during your own loading period. It depends greatly on the game in question. Sure, experiment with loading images from "disk" .. try it.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen several application that downloads configuration and metadata on application load, some also download images and audio files.
Usually they store the data in the documents or cache folder, so the they will not have to wait for download during the game.

Another technique I encountered is downloading a zip file and expanding it in the cache directory. Most of these apps do not load the files the next time unless something new is needed.

Do not load the images to the memory, not inside an nsarray nor nsmutabearray. You do not have enough memory to cache images like this.  You should just predownload them

**Edit:**

You can use the application loading stage to download more resources from your servers (images, audio, plist files) but after they are download and stored in the file system they should be treated like resources that exists in your IPA. They should be loaded into memory only when they are needed

Comment: So you're saying that apps typically make use of the cache to store image data?

Comment: @Fitzy when your application starts and download resources that are not inside the application IPA (more game levels resources) you should store this data in he file system, the cache directory is a good candidate for this. Better than the document directory